# Should I use LSF or implement my own job schedulers?

Tags: hadoop, akka, job-scheduling, lsf

We do some file crunching\computation within our compnay Simply put, we have a job or a task involves reading a huge file with more than a billion records, parse through the files and do some cleansing and write the cleansed data to another file. We have hundreds of such jobs that are constantly being created, submitted, ran. Each job deals with its own files, so we don't have to worry about concurrency issues.

To achieve this, we have built our own scheduling system (a combination or MainFrame and Java). Our current throughput is about 40 million records per hour.

In our pursuit to better this (and provide more fault tolerance) we are evaluating IBM's LSF to help us with this scheduling and job creation.

Does any of you feel that using LSF might be an over kill for this problem? I can think of achieving the same using a an actor-model implementation in AKKA and writing my own Job Scheduler around it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know what an LSF is, but for your problem description I'd rather start looking  at Hadoop stack (and maybe Spark if you have latency requirements). I'd only start to look at Akka if you have near-real time processing requirements that you can't satisfy with batch Map/Reduce jobs.

Comment: The files that I work with ranges from hundreds of MB's to 100 gigs. Is that a good enough file size for Hadoop? I keep reading and hearing that file sizes have to be in the order of Terabytes to see any real performance gains. Also my my crunching logic is pretty simple, it is going to go through each line/record in the file and apply some transformation and write it back to a new file (there is no "reduce").

Answer (score 0):

My comment is too long, so I make it an answer, although it's not really answering your question (not yet anyways).

There is a tradeoff between bringing in a new technology and rolling out your own solution. Do you need to do cross-referencing between records in different files or within one file? If not, and you process files line by line, there is a million of ways to script it without using any framework. Bringing in Akka (or any other framework for that's sake) may drag in some infrastructural requirements that may be more expensive to satisfy than writing an actual service.

TLDR: yes, you can use Akka to do this (as well as many other approaches), but there are too many unknowns to decide whether it's the 'best' solution (quotes because there is no definition of 'best' at this point).

Comment: I agree with your point. In my case, not only i need to file crunch, I also need to monitor the progress etc, which is exactly what technologies like Hadoop brings to the table. I guess AKKA and Hadoop are not competing technologies, just different paradigms, dont know what I was thinking when I wrote that

Comment: Hm, I did not have much luck with MapReduce monitoring tools (I was using Pig at a time), so not sure how much progress and monitoring would you get out of the box with Hadoop. And if you use your own thing it's relatively easy to plug in something like Graphite or statsd to get custom metrics and a nice UI.